# How do I place a textbox on/in a button in the same form?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button class="action">Purchase</button>
      <input class="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" value="1">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.action
{ width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
.quantity
{ width: 30px;
  float: right;  
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpz0g7vt/3/

I want the textbox to float:right ON TOP OF the button. That is, overlapping it. Currently the textbox is floating AFTER the button.

It should look as if the `<input>` is a child of `<button>` as seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpz0g7vt/4/

What is the best way to achieve this?

I could hardcode the placement with CSS margins, but I worry this is bad practice and/or leads to undesired behavior in different browsers.

Thank you.

Comment: *why* do you want this?

Comment: Please inlcude all relevant code **in the question itself** , preferably as a [MCVE]. Any interactive elements (eg textbox) are invalid children of  `button` elements. Note that `button` is a submit button by default.

Comment: @Lux In a webgame, the button is used to purchase an item; the textbox indicates quantity to purchase. I believe (desire) they should be displayed as indicated in my post.

Comment: @JonP Thank you for confirming interactive elements are invalid children to buttons -- good to know.

Comment: @JonP I will either edit or repost with all code in the question, and hopefully with a screen cap of the webgame for context, per Lux's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropdown-action
{ width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-textfield
{ width: 30px;
  float: right;  
}

form {
  display: inline-flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
         <input class="dropdown-textfield" name="quantity" type="text" value="1">
      <button class="dropdown-action">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmm, not quite. The textbox should be on/in the button, so overlapping it. Imagine if the <input> was a child of <button>, that's what it should LOOK like.

Comment: However, inline-flex looks useful... perhaps could utilize inline-flex in combination with margin...